# networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers explanation

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have a simple graph like the one below:

```py
    edge_list = [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

I want to use the `relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers()` method to
label the nodes with consecutive integers like it says in the documentation.
What was I expecting from the use of the method is the following dict:

```py
    {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3:3}
```

But I am getting the following:

```py
    {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}
```

Could someone explain to me why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edge list defines three nodes, `1,2,3` (with four edges among them).

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

edge_list = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]

G.add_edges_from(edge_list)

print(G.nodes())  # [1, 2, 3]

GG = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

print(GG.nodes())  # [0, 1, 2]

mapping = {k: GG.nodes[k]["old_id"] for k in GG.nodes()}
print(mapping) # {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```

In your output, it seems that at some point the nodes were (re)named using `0,1,2`. In that case, renaming node labels then has no effect, so dictionary keys and values match.